# How to override a static generic method with different type parameters?

Tags: typescript

I have two interfaces, of which one extends the other. One is the base interface:

```js
export interface Function<T, R> {
    apply: (t: T) => R;
}

export class Function<T, R> {
    public static create<T, R>(apply: (t: T) => R): Function<T, R> {
        return new class extends Function<T, R> {
            public apply = (t: T): R => { return apply(t); };
        }();
    }
}
```

and the other equally simple:

```js
export interface Unary<T> extends Function<T, T> {
    apply: (t: T) => T;
}

export class Unary<T> extends Function<T, T> {
    public static create<T>(apply: (t: T) => T): Unary<T> {
        return new class extends Unary<T> {
            public apply = (t: T): T => { return apply(t); };
        }();
    }
}
```

Here's the [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgMQFclsYEIkAeAFQBo4AlAPjgG8AoOLuTMMAGwCeALjgAKGKOoBKOAF4WDANzsAvu3ahIsONn6YAzgYLFS5KnUYsO3OGEIAjfgmxwDMTGVfYowT8Bp6ZjFeARFxSTgZeUVpUSISMgpAqzZOW25fGEIoJDgkYAB3XX0jOFBUJAATYwSzZMtmNIyWu0dnV1CheQipOMYYtjgsnLyuwQlpJThVFVaZsSn0rnV1TXBoeGRUDBw8AFUkTChBGhYK4Gra0ySLemprZZ4+IVEJPsHqFTWtTZLDYyHY6nB7lECVGomRLmFKgmzcexOFxuDxeXS+fxnEIvcLvKKyBT40RAk5nZqtEa5fJFf5lC5XOAkkGPea2REdZ5hHp4mRSQasYbAbJU8aTaazJ62VSLObcVbsIA) The error I get is:

> Class static side 'typeof Unary' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof Function'.
> Types of property 'create' are incompatible.
> Types of parameters 'apply' and 'apply' are incompatible.
> Type 'R' is not assignable to type 'T'.
> 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'R'.ts(2417)
> function.ts(31, 29): This type parameter might need an `extends T` constraint.

The suggested solution does not help. It just leads to another suggestion to add `extends R` to type parameter T. Additionally, I don't want to impose such a restriction.

Since the type parameters for `Function` are `<T, T>` I would expect that `R` is the same as `T`. Interesting here is also that the error does not come up for the type parameter list, but for the function parameter.

How can this be resolved?

##### More Details

The names have to be as they are here. The reason is that this code emulates Java's functional interfaces (and here in particular [java.util.function.Function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html) and [java.util.function.UnaryOperator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/UnaryOperator.html)), with their default method(s). Java can create instances of these interfaces, which automatically inherit the default methods. This is not possible in TS, so I added the factory methods, to stay as close as possible to the Java semantics.

Comment: Could you change the names so that you're not shadowing both the JS `Function` object and the TS `Function` interface, so that it does not distract from your issue?

Comment: Additionally you are not using your interfaces at all in the code example; could you either remove them or modify your code to use them?

Comment: Static members are inherited, and so their types must be compatible, as per [ms/TS#4628](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4628), but you are not properly inheriting `Unary.create`'s type from `MyFunction.create`.  Static members do not see the type parameters of their instance type; the fact that you named `apply()`'s generic type parameters `T` and `R` has nothing to do with the `T` and `R` from the containing class.  Since `MyFunction.create` cannot be used to make a function whose return type differs from the arg type, it is invalid.

Comment: But you're not asking why; you're asking how it can be resolved.  That depends on whether you care about static inheritance or not.  If you don't, then you can just work around it by blocking the compiler's knowledge of the parent `create`'s existence, like perhaps [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKp9Gw).  If you do then we need more careful investigation.  How do you want to proceed?

Comment: @jcalz I added a bit more info why the names as they are. I have not added any code that uses the interfaces, because that doesn't really make a difference. The factory methods are to create very specific types, so inheritance is not important here. I'll probably suppress the TS error then.

Comment: I know the type parameters in the factory method have nothing to do with those of the interface (after all static members cannot access the type parameters of their enclosing structure), but for consistency I named them the same to avoid confusion and show the intent. I'll check the link you provided, thanks!

Comment: The names do not have to be as they are *for Stack Overflow*, only for your use case which this question isn't really about, right?  JavaScript has a global `Function` object and TypeScript has a global `Function` interface, and this code shadows both of those.  That's generally considered bad practice, since it leads to potential confusion.  Unless you want the question and answer to discuss best practices around naming instead of focusing on the type parameter issue, I'd suggest you change the names *in the Stack Overflow question* to avoid the topic entirely.

Comment: Ah, and I still suggest you remove the interfaces from the question if you're not using them in the question.  You say "because that doesn't really make a difference"... if so, then removing them will make things clearer.  I'm happy to make these edits for you if you want.  Or you can make them.  Or, if you still don't want to do that, I will just disengage so we don't belabor this point, and others can work with you on your terms.  Let me know how to proceed!